# Chat bots: ensuring serial processing of messages on a per-conversation basis in clustered environment

Tags: concurrency, message-queue, messaging, distributed, chatbot

In the context of writing a Messenger chat bot in a cloud environment, I'm facing some concurrency issues.

Specifically, **I would like to ensure that incoming messages from the same conversation are processed one after the other.**

As a constraint, I'm processing the messages with workers in a Cloud environment (i.e the worker pool is of variable size and worker instances are potentially short-lived and may crash). Also, low latency is important.

So abstracting a little, my requirements are:

- I have a stream of incoming messages
- each of these messages has a 'topic key' (the conversation id)
- the set of topics is not known ahead-of-time and is virtually infinite
- I want to ensure that messages of the same topic are processed serially
- on a cluster of potentially ephemeral workers
- if possible, I would like reliability guarantees e.g making sure that each message is processed exactly once.

**My questions are:**

1. Is there a ***name*** for this concurrency scenario?.
2. Are there ***technologies*** (message brokers, coordination services, etc.) which implement this out of the box?
3. If not, what ***algorithms*** can I use to implement this on top of lower-level concurrency tools? (distributed locks, actors, queues, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a widely-accepted name for the scenario, but a common strategy to solve that type of problem is to route your messages so that all messages with the same topic key end up at the same destination.  A couple of technologies that will do this for you:

- With Apache ActiveMQ, HornetQ, or Apache ActiveMQ Artemis, you could use your topic key as the JMSXGroupId [to ensure all messages with the same topic key are processed in-order by the same consumer, with failover](http://activemq.apache.org/message-groups.html)
- With Apache Kafka, you could use your topic key as the partition key, which [will also ensure all messages with the same topic key are processed in-order by the same consumer](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#intro_consumers)

Some message broker vendors refer to this requirement as *Message Grouping*, *Sticky Sessions*, or *Sticky Message Load Balancing*.

Another common strategy on messaging systems with weaker delivery/ordering guarantees (like [Amazon SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/)) is to simply include a sequence number in the message and leave it up to the destination to resequence and request redelivery of missing messages as needed.

Comment: Thank you, Message Grouping as implemented by ActiveMQ or HornetQ is exactly what I needed.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to complete your answers with my own search.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix this by using a queue and a set. What I can think of is sending every message object in queue and processing it as first in first out. But while adding it in queue add topic name in set and while taking it out for processing remove topic name from set.
So now if you have any topic in set then don't add another message object of same topic in queue.
I hope this will help you. All the best :)

Comment: So essentially this consists of A - using a distributed lock on every topic and B - immediately dropping every message that fails to acquire the lock. I'm not fond of A, and B is not acceptable in my use case.